# Can I change Creation date of table without dropping it in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a table which was generated 4 years back. But when I was analyzing tables created 15 days back , it showed me that table as well. Is there any way it could happen without dropping and creating it again.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow .. please what do you mean about createing date of table, with system table that stores this info ?

Comment: In sys.tables which shows table creation date

Comment: you can not change the creating date, are you sure the column that changed is create_dt not modified_dt ?

Comment: How are you determining which tables were created 15 days ago? (Please update the question with this information.)

Comment: The table `create_date` will change only when the table was dropped and re-created. Tools like SSDT may apply schema changes by recreating the table while preserving data so that might explain why the `create_date` changed.

Comment: Yes Ahmed! it is create_Date not modified date

Comment: Hi Richard! i just chckd by create_Date>getdate()-15

Comment: Are changes to this database done predominantly through SQL Server Management Studio designers? If so, what's the state of everyone who works on its "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" option (under `Tools -> Options -> Designers`)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of SQL server. In SQL 2000 you could do that by changing the system tables with sp_configure setting allow updates to 1. This is not possible in SQL 2005 and up.